# How to access and change child's state from Parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

You are given uncontrollable child component.
Parent component stores number of counters and renders that amount of child components. It has two buttons Add counter and Increment all counters.

1. You are not allowed to edit child component.
2. Implement
   incrementCounters so that it increments counters of all child
   components that are rendered.

   incrementCounters = () => {
   // TODO: implement
   };

---

```
export class ChildCounter extends React.Component{
    state = {
        counter: 0
    };

    increment = () => {
        this.setState(({ counter }) => ({
            counter: counter + 1
        }));
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Counter: {this.state.counter}
                <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

---

```
import {ChildCounter} from "./Child";


class App extends React.Component {

    state = {counters:1}


    addCounter = () => {
     let counterRn = this.state.counters + 1;
     this.setState({counters:counterRn})
    };

   incrementAll = () => {

   }

   render() {
   return (
       <div>
                { new Array(this.state.counters).fill(0).map((_, index) => {
                    return <ChildCounter key={index} />;
                })
                }
           <br/>
           <button style={{marginRight:10}} onClick={this.addCounter}>Add Counter</button>
           <button onClick={this.incrementAll}>Increment all counters</button>
       </div>
   )
   }
}
```

Comment: *i can not change child component* Why not? That would be the most straightforward way to do it by far IMO

Comment: it should be solved that way

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't know why you don't want to do it with state, it would be much better I think
by using an array of counter values and then incrementing them all at once, and having your child component as controller component.

With refs, I was not able to come up with a good solution (not sure).
So I have passed the code here, and What I did is, I used a react hook called `useImperativeHandle` to make your child component take the ref and expose the inner `increment` method.
And then I added an array of refs in your parent component.
So when the user click increment all, basically you loop over your refs and call the inner increment method.
I am still not sure a correct way to implement array of refs, but I think this should do it.
And I have already written this with hooks to make it simpler to understand.

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useEffect,
  createRef,
  forwardRef,
  useImperativeHandle
} from "react";

const ChildCounter = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const increment = () => {
    setCounter((c) => c + 1);
  };

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    increment
  }));

  return (
    <div>
      Counter: {counter}
      <button onClick={increment}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
});

const App = () => {
  const [counters, setCounters] = useState(1);
  const [elRefs, setElRefs] = useState([]);

  const addCounter = () => {
    setCounters((c) => c + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setElRefs((elRefs) =>
      Array(counters)
        .fill()
        .map((_, i) => elRefs[i] || createRef())
    );
  }, [counters]);

  const incrementAll = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < elRefs.length; i++) {
      if (elRefs[i] && elRefs[i].current) {
        elRefs[i].current.increment();
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {new Array(counters).fill(0).map((_, index) => {
        return <ChildCounter ref={elRefs[index]} key={index} />;
      })}
      <br />
      <button style={{ marginRight: 10 }} onClick={addCounter}>
        Add Counter
      </button>
      <button onClick={incrementAll}>Increment all counters</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-neumann-37e2q?file=/src/App.js:0-1327

Comment: That requires changing the child though, which OP says is not allowed. It's an X/Y problem for sure, but still

Comment: Yeah, this is the only solution i thought of which won't effect the child component and only extend some properties, but still needs to add some more things, and the child still needs some work to support ref, in the example it doesn't support

Comment: the problem is: You are given uncontrollable child component.
Parent component stores number of counters and renders that amount of child components. It has two buttons Add counter and Increment all counters.  You are not allowed to edit child component.  Implement incrementCounters so that it increments counters of all child components that are rendered.

Comment: incrementCounters = () => {
    // TODO: implement
  };

Comment: yes, I think that should do it.
I have attached a codesandbox link as well for you to try out.

Answer (score 0):

This is *technically possible* to achieve without changing the child by passing down a ref from the parent instead, and have the parent use the ref to access the `increment` method on the child whenever `incrementAll` is called:

```
childCounterChildren = [];

incrementAll = () => {
    for (const counter of this.childCounterChildren) {
        counter.increment();
    }
}
```

```
<ChildCounter
    key={index}
    ref={(childCounter) => { if (childCounter) { this.childCounterChildren.push(childCounter); }}}
/>;
```

```js
class ChildCounter extends React.Component {
    state = {
        counter: 0
    };

    increment = () => {
        this.setState(({ counter }) => ({
            counter: counter + 1
        }));
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Counter: {this.state.counter}
                <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    state = { counters: 1 }
    childCounterChildren = [];
    addCounter = () => {
        let counterRn = this.state.counters + 1;
        this.setState({ counters: counterRn })
    };

    incrementAll = () => {
        for (const counter of this.childCounterChildren) {
            counter.increment();
        }
    }
    componentWillUpdate() {
      this.childCounterChildren.length = 0;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {new Array(this.state.counters).fill(0).map((_, index) => {
                    return <ChildCounter
                        key={index}
                        ref={(childCounter) => { if (childCounter) { this.childCounterChildren.push(childCounter); }}}
                    />;
                })
                }
                <br />
                <button style={{ marginRight: 10 }} onClick={this.addCounter}>Add Counter</button>
                <button onClick={this.incrementAll}>Increment all counters</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

But it's quite weird. For a real-world problem, I'd recommend [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) instead.